# Fractions class python

Tags: python, class, fractions, magic-methods

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to create a class Fractions and all the function are "magic methods". The problem is my professor never taught us magic methods. I've used

```
   __init__
```

but never used any other magic methods. I have two days to program this and I need some guidance on constructing this code. The closest to what I need to program I found here: https://gist.github.com/mustaa/2350807
But I can't understand what is going on in that code

The magic methods are:

```
    class Fraction: #I need it in a form like the one on github, but easier to understand
    __init__  #construct a rational number with a given numerator and denominator
    __add__   #add two fractions
    __sub__   #subtract to fractions
    __eq__    #check if 2 fractions are equal
    __ne__    #check if 2 are not equal
    __lt__    #check if one fraction is less than the other
    __le__    #check if <=
    __gt__    #check if one fraction is greater than the other
    __ge__    #check if >=
    __float__ #gets float representation of fraction called by float()
    __repr__  #gets a string representation of the Fraction instance, called by str()
```

Once I get the skeleton code for:

```
    class Fraction, __add__, __eq__
```

I will be able to finish the rest of the assignment myself.

Comment: I have no idea what you're supposed to deliver for your assignment from your question.

Comment: They are all explained in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Comment: The code for Python's official `Fraction` factory function is all open source and is reasonably well documented, including test cases...
If you are using IPython/Jupyter, `from fractions import Fraction` and then executing `Fraction??` (with two question marks will show the source code).

Comment: Thanks for the link. My professor never introduced these, I thought they were something that he just made up for the purpose of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to implement the magic `__add__` and `__eq__` methods for the useless `Integer` class. I'll leave it to you to adapt it to your `Fraction` class.

```
class Integer:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Integer(self._value + other._value)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._value == other._value
```

Comment: Adding `isinstance(other, Integer)` is probably a good idea for `__eq__` but +1 for the simple example.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah, the example is supposed to be as devoid of distractions as possible: the signal is about how to write magic methods in general, so anything else (such as type checking) would be noise.